# How to use grepl to detect missing characters

Tags: r

I am trying the code below so that if there is neither "/" nor "\" the output is an error and the application stops, but it does not work.  I cannot see what is wrong with it.

```
 if (grepl("/", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)) { # mac style
     OUTpath<- paste(paste(unlist(strsplit(OUTpath, "/", fixed=TRUE)), collapse="/"), "/", sep="")
   } else 
     if (grepl("\\", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)) { # windows style
       OUTpath<- paste(paste(unlist(strsplit(OUTpath, "\\", fixed=TRUE)), collapse="\\"), "\\", sep="")
     } else
       if(!grepl("/", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE) || !grepl("\\", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)){
       trueFalse = FALSE
       errorMessage("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath or no path specification in PARAMS file. Cannot open connection\n
                             You can edit your input file and save the changes. Afterwards, stop and restart glycoPipe and upload file again")
       stop("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath\n")
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working on my end. I removed one `if` statement that was nested. I also changed curly braces a bit. Not quite sure this would work for your application, maybe you could include more details.

```
OUTpath <- 'aa' # Gives error
OUTpath <- 'aa\\aa' # Produces 'aa\\aa\\'
OUTpath <- 'aa\aa' # Produces error
OUTpath <- 'aa/aa' # Produces 'aa/aa/'

if (grepl("/", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)) { # mac style
  OUTpath<- paste(paste(unlist(strsplit(OUTpath, "/", fixed=TRUE)), collapse="/"), "/", sep="")
} else {
  if (grepl("\\", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)) { # windows style
    OUTpath<- paste(paste(unlist(strsplit(OUTpath, "\\", fixed=TRUE)), collapse="\\"), "\\", sep="")
  } else {
  #  if(!grepl("/", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE) || !grepl("\\", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)){
      trueFalse = FALSE
      errorMessage("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath or no path specification in PARAMS file. Cannot open connection\n
                   You can edit your input file and save the changes. Afterwards, stop and restart glycoPipe and upload file again")
      stop("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath\n")

  }
}
```

## UPDATE

You should use `file.path()` function to make paths independent of the `OS`.

```
file.path(getwd(), 'lala', 'ee')
[1] "C:/Users/Matias/Desktop/lala/ee"
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: @gccd Sure! Don't forget to mark the question as answered!

Comment: I do not know how to mark the questions as answered.  I do not see any links or buttons.

Comment: Hi, the path is read from a file.  I have written \errorTests\OUT and the error is not detected.  The error is displayed only when the path is blank.  Could you try this please?  Thanks

Comment: What I realize is that both "\" and "/" are acceptable because "\\" means "\".  The problem I see is that the path is not created when "\" is used.  I am working with LINUX Ubuntu 17.04 and that may make a difference.  What I think I have to test is whether the path has been created or not.

Comment: @gccd You should see a checkmark below the number 0 with arrows. I am not sure about your application. The fact that begging with `\` doesn't work is because R thinks you are escaping the `e` next to the `\`. You should take a look at `file.path()` function or make your question more clear to what you ACTUALLY need to do

Comment: Thank you!  file.path() is great.  It simplifies the code a lot.